# How to add existing cpp codes to an objective-c project?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode

I have a class written in C++, its declaration and implementation are seperated into .h and .cpp files.
And I want to invoke it in an iOS objective-C project with Xcode.
So I changed the suffix of my *.m file to *.mm and the compilation is OK, but failed in the linking step.

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

It seems that the compiler did not discover the *.cpp file of the implementation of my class.
Then when I move all the implementation into it's *.h files, the program works but the codes are ugly.

Can anyone help？I have tried to change the suffix of my cpp into mm, but no success.

Comment: What were the missing symbols? Were they part of the .cpp?

Comment: which symbols? Did you link the c++ runtime library (check the project settings)

Comment: I would have 2 header files one for cpp and other for objcpp and the cpp calls objcpp functions and vice versa

Comment: Did you rename *.cpp files to *.mm? And was these files added to "Compile Sources"?

Comment: @АлексейАбдулин  My *.h and *.cpp codes are in a folder in blue color showed in Xcode. I think my problem is the files under this folder is not added to the "Compile Source List". How can I add them by hand or should I convert the whole folder into a Group?

Comment: You will select your project -> choose target you need -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources

Comment: @АлексейАбдулин Your suggestion is right, and create a new Group and re-add the *.cpp file is OK too! THX!